# how can we Increase the MaxExpiryDate/TTL more then 365 Days in Cloud Anchors ARCore android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, augmented-reality, arcore

In Persistent Cloud Anchors is any workaround or possible to increase the TTL(Time To Live) more then 365 days.

I tried this [Management API](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/cloud-anchors/management-api) , in which i can able the modify the expiry date with in 365 days. But,I need to Increase the Max Time limit more then 365 Day's.

I know Persistent cloud anchors only support up to 365 days, but is there any possible to achieve more then 365 days (like updating the anchor data periodically) .